# Iterate two lists in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-2.7

I am having a list of file names created using `dirs = os.listdir(dir/path)`.

Also I am exporting a data set from a csv file. `stocks = csv.reader(open('config.csv', 'rb'))`

Sample stock data:

> fileName1,url1
>
> fileName2,url2

What I need to do is get the each url for each file in the `dirs` list in a python script. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by `get each url`? Are you going to make a web request?

Comment: Ok, so you want all entries from 'stocks' where the fileName appears in 'dirs'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pytho provides a built-in function for this, [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for dir, stock, in zip(dirs, stocks)
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = ["cat", "dogs"]
>>> b = ["http://cat-service.com", "http://dogs-care.com"]
>>> for animal, site in zip(a, b):
    print(animal, site)


cat http://cat-service.com
dogs http://dogs-care.com
```

See, It's not hard, right? Python makes our life easier! :)

Alternative: If performance **really** matters, use `itertools.izip`.

**Update**

Turns out the answer above is not what the OP was asking. Well, same as Steve, I'd use a dictionary for this:

```
stock_dict = dict(stock)
urls = [stock_dict.get(file, "Not found") for file in dirs]
```

Demo:

We assume there are 3 files in the directory, two of them are listed.

```
>>> stock = [("fileName1","url1"), ("fileName2","url2")]
>>> stock_dict = dict(stock)
>>> dirs = ["fileName1", "fileName2", "fileName3"]
>>> urls = [stock_dict.get(file, "Not found") for file in dirs]
>>> urls
['url1', 'url2', 'Not found']
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think it's what @Yasitha wanted. At least your code doesn't work right if theres fileName1, fileName3 but not fileName2 in the path.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I am looking for is get the url when the file name match with name in the stock data. Eg: Lets assume there is a record called "file1" in the dirs and I want to Iterate through the stocks and if there is a record for file1 get the url. Need to do this for all elements in dirs.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming everything fits in memory:

```
stockslookup = dict(stocks)
urls = [stockslookup[filename] for filename in dirs]
```

Note that the filename has to be exactly the same string, so you might want to use `os.path.abspath` on both (or `os.path.normpath`).

Comment: That's a nice way to do it. I was thinking about something with list comprehension, but this is way smarter!

Comment: @EarlGrey: if both lists were sorted then you could do a merge-like operation that's O(n+m) time and O(1)-ish memory (ish becomes actually if you assume a fixed upper limit on filename length in the file...). But assuming you have the memory budget, `dict` is the "obvious" way to look up anything :-)

Comment: I'm actually a bit confused about what the OP is asking.

Comment: @alKid: I think the "sample stock data" in the question is the contents of `config.csv`, and the request is to look up each filename in the file to get its corresponding url. But obviously if I'm wrong then my code is wrong :-)